# Toast and Progress dialog edges cut off

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, progressdialog, android-toast

I tested my app on various phones and native stuff like progress dialog and Toast messages look normal, but when I started testing on the phones with Android 5.0, edges of progress dialog/Toast got cut off.

[image: Toast]

[image: Progress Dialog example]

What am I doing wrong? On every phone with OS lower than Lollipop it works fine.

My Style, as requested:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <!--   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#1d2128</item>
    <!--<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>-->
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/top_bar_logo</item>
    <!--<item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.MainActivity" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is the theme of your app?

Comment: i tried both android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar and Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Non of them worked

Comment: Please post the same, are you maintaining different folders for `Values`?

Comment: i edited the question and added my style, i see i have different folder for Values, but syles in them are the same, except the one in folder values-v19, that one is a little bit different

Comment: which device are you using ?

Comment: i am using Samsung Galaxy S6, but i just deleted values v19 folder and now it works ?? Whoa, thanks man, you helped a lot. If you want, write the answer below and i will accept it as correct one, something like "do not use  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in the style.xml"

Comment: I would suggest you go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) once :) From the docs: `Newer versions of Android have additional themes available to applications, and you might want to use these while running on those platforms while still being compatible with older versions. You can accomplish this through a custom theme that uses resource selection to switch between different parent themes, based on the platform version.`

Comment: going through it right away! Thanks! :)

Comment: You welcome matey, happy trucking :)

Comment: As for future references: currently the second image is not being shown.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue remove `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` from your themes.xml
This will also fix weird offsets and text wrapping behaviour when displaying `EditText.setError("error");`